# elementFromPoint in specified group

Tags: svg, find, position, element

in SVG document

can I use elementFromPoint() in only specified group?

I am trying to find all Elements which take up specific coordinate.

for finding line or circle intersections.

to do this and undo or redo function, my SVG append every element to group whose ID is 
linearly increase.

such as finding element by point on lastest made group and

lastest-1 made group.

I also tried set display attribute to none and elemetFromPoint again, but have no luck.

any idea about finding element from point in only specified group?

thanks in advanced!